# Angular 9 : rxjs 6 : how to return a manual Observable of Error

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-observables

In my Angular app , and to test some features in HorLigne mode , i need to mock http usefull responses :

- the 200 OK return containing some data
- the 404 KO return with no data

Usually i tried this :

```
@Injectable()
export class VerifService {
  mockedResult = false;
  verifData(mail, uuid) {
    if (this.mockedResult) {
      return ObservaleOf({ status: "OK" }).pipe(delay(3000));
    } else {
      return throwError({ status: 500, message: "not found" }).pipe(
        delay(3000)
      );
    }
  }
}
```

After that within my component i m doing this :

```
this.verifService.verifData(mail, uuid).subscribe(data=>{
  console.log('THIS WORKS')
}, err => {
  console.log('THIS FAILS')
}
```

For the case **mockedResult**  equals true , the successful 200 OK return is working

But for the 404 error return , it's not working

Is there any other good way to mock the **404** **error** **observable** return ?

**Suggestions ?**

Comment: I would imagine that should work. Do you set `mockedResult` to `false` so `throwError` can be traversed?

Comment: Using `throwError` is correct. `delay()` has no effect here. Can you make a demo replicating this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where is not working. If you need to pause for some time:

```
interval(1000).pipe(
  switchMap(
    () => throwError(new Error())
  )
)
```

Pipe will not work as when throwError the observable already been stopped.